How should I protect this cable behind kitchen peninsula drawers?
I’m rewiring a kitchen (San Jose, CA). I’ve added a receptacle at the end of our kitchen peninsula. This is the last receptacle on one of the two 20 amp circuits for appliances.

I routed 12/2 romex along the “back” of the peninsula from the previous receptacle at the wall. This goes behind a built in microwave, a range, and three drawers. The box itself is a shallow single gang box (a standard depth box is unlikely to fit the clearance of the drawer).
The inspector indicated this cable needs to be protected. What are the options here? Do I need to run armored cable? And if so how does that feed into the box with integral clamps? If not, can I enclose the current wire with non metallic tubing that terminates outside the box? Or are 1x2 runners sufficient in a case like this?

From the photo, it appears that you perhaps had the cable make a tight U-turn near the end of the new run.  Is that correct (it's hard to tell in the shadow of the photo)?  If so, why was this choice made?  Was the inspector concerned about it at all?

Wire mold could work:

Source, not endorsed
These wire molds have lots of different corner handlings. You might be able to put the Romex in it, or you may have to switch to THHN wires.

Yeah, metallic surface raceway would do the trick, but would probably require the OP to switch to THHN for the run (generally not a huge deal though)

Thanks for the suggestions. If I were to switch wire types, would it be better to just switch to armored cable and swap for a metal box, plus a junction box to transition (which would be needed for the THNN as well)?

Smurf tube would work too, no?

@Huesmann Smurf tube doesn't provide "physical protection"
